# How can I expand / adjust the size (height) of a minipage to include the entire wrapfigure?

Tags: minipage, wrapfigure

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
{\huge Seth Creewnusher}
\par\vspace{-2mm}
{\rule{\textwidth}{0.2mm}
\end{minipage}
\par\vspace{2mm}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{36mm}
\vspace{-5mm}
\includegraphics[width=36mm]{1.png}
\vspace{-10mm}
\end{wrapfigure}
Golden Road Solutions\par\vspace{2mm}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ac lacus at libero pellentesque feugiat sit amet hendrerit dolor. Pellentesque lobortis sollicitudin risus nec volutpat. Vivamus nibh neque, pellentesque ac tortor a, malesuada euismod mi. Sed sit amet ante mattis metus finibus tempus a ornare odio.\par\vspace{2mm}Integer posuere sem ut nisi fermentum feugiat. Praesent dictum libero lacus, vitae tincidunt nisi mollis in. Sed imperdiet ante at ligula fringilla, non aliquam dui egestas. Maecenas blandit ligula augue, vitae ultricies nunc sagittis nec. Sed dui purus, varius eu posuere vitae, consectetur et leo.
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{6mm}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
{\huge Trevin Smeeltood}
\par\vspace{-2mm}
{\rule{\textwidth}{0.2mm}
\end{minipage}
\par\vspace{2mm}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}[0mm]{36mm}
\vspace{-5mm}
\includegraphics[width=36mm]{3.jpg}
\vspace{-10mm}
\end{wrapfigure}
Labyrinth Microsystems\par\vspace{2mm}Aliquam scelerisque, mauris quis maximus venenatis, arcu neque vestibulum ante, et iaculis lorem diam vel ex.\par\vspace{2mm}Etiam consequat sollicitudin tortor a varius. Phasellus vel rutrum turpis. Donec orci lacus, ultrices eget interdum eget, suscipit et quam. Donec consequat et nisl a porta.
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{6mm}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
{\huge Rowena Zodsinch}
\par\vspace{-2mm}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.2mm}
\end{minipage}
\par\vspace{2mm}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{36mm}
\vspace{-5mm}
\includegraphics[width=36mm]{4.jpg}
\vspace{-10mm}
\end{wrapfigure}
Vortex Microsystems\par\vspace{2mm}Morbi euismod felis quam, nec ultrices elit tincidunt eu. Nam tempus et est a hendrerit. Nunc blandit orci nec nisi tempus, id aliquam sapien porta. Morbi quis condimentum mauris. Cras a consectetur erat, quis laoreet neque. Cras mattis quis nisl at varius. Vestibulum ligula sem, imperdiet congue erat nec, congue euismod orci. Mauris vulputate neque eros, nec semper velit feugiat eu. Suspendisse interdum lacus a suscipit rhoncus.
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

that produces the following result:
[image]

I've added an `fbox` around the last 2 `minipage`s to illustrate the problem: The `minipage` size (height) only expands to size of the text around the `wrapfigure` and not to the size of the `wrapfigure` itself. As a result, when the text is shorter than the `wrapfigure` (as is the case in the 2nd `minipage`), the next `minipage` starts after the text (respecting the `vspace`) and sits over the `wrapfigure`.

Is there a way to have the `minipage` automatically expand and adjust its size to the size of the `wrapfigure` or the text (which ever is longer)? Ideally I would end up with something like this:

[image]

Comment: Apparently CTAN contributor Donald Arseneau has a [macro](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/WA5NoRB-XWw/ZYmxkhUfUfAJ) for exactly what I need. Adding `\wrapfill` right after the text does the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `\wrapfill` macro by CTAN contributor Donald Arseneau has the desired effect, when added right after the text that is wrapping the figure:

```
\makeatletter
\def\wrapfill{\par
  \ifx\parshape\WF@fudgeparshape
    \nobreak
    \ifnum\c@WF@wrappedlines>\@ne
      \advance\c@WF@wrappedlines\m@ne
      \vskip\c@WF@wrappedlines\baselineskip
      \global\c@WF@wrappedlines\z@
    \fi
    \allowbreak
    \WF@finale
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

The full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\wrapfill{\par
  \ifx\parshape\WF@fudgeparshape
    \nobreak
    \ifnum\c@WF@wrappedlines>\@ne
      \advance\c@WF@wrappedlines\m@ne
      \vskip\c@WF@wrappedlines\baselineskip
      \global\c@WF@wrappedlines\z@
    \fi
    \allowbreak
    \WF@finale
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
{\huge Seth Creewnusher}
\par\vspace{-2mm}
{\rule{\textwidth}{0.2mm}
\end{minipage}
\par\vspace{2mm}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{36mm}
\vspace{-5mm}
\includegraphics[width=36mm]{1.png}
\vspace{-10mm}
\end{wrapfigure}
Golden Road Solutions\par\vspace{2mm}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ac lacus at libero pellentesque feugiat sit amet hendrerit dolor. Pellentesque lobortis sollicitudin risus nec volutpat. Vivamus nibh neque, pellentesque ac tortor a, malesuada euismod mi. Sed sit amet ante mattis metus finibus tempus a ornare odio.\par\vspace{2mm}Integer posuere sem ut nisi fermentum feugiat. Praesent dictum libero lacus, vitae tincidunt nisi mollis in. Sed imperdiet ante at ligula fringilla, non aliquam dui egestas. Maecenas blandit ligula augue, vitae ultricies nunc sagittis nec. Sed dui purus, varius eu posuere vitae, consectetur et leo.
\wrapfill
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{6mm}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
{\huge Trevin Smeeltood}
\par\vspace{-2mm}
{\rule{\textwidth}{0.2mm}
\end{minipage}
\par\vspace{2mm}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}[0mm]{36mm}
\vspace{-5mm}
\includegraphics[width=36mm]{3.jpg}
\vspace{-10mm}
\end{wrapfigure}
Labyrinth Microsystems\par\vspace{2mm}Aliquam scelerisque, mauris quis maximus venenatis, arcu neque vestibulum ante, et iaculis lorem diam vel ex.\par\vspace{2mm}Etiam consequat sollicitudin tortor a varius. Phasellus vel rutrum turpis. Donec orci lacus, ultrices eget interdum eget, suscipit et quam. Donec consequat et nisl a porta.
\wrapfill
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{6mm}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
{\huge Rowena Zodsinch}
\par\vspace{-2mm}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.2mm}
\end{minipage}
\par\vspace{2mm}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{36mm}
\vspace{-5mm}
\includegraphics[width=36mm]{4.jpg}
\vspace{-10mm}
\end{wrapfigure}
Vortex Microsystems\par\vspace{2mm}Morbi euismod felis quam, nec ultrices elit tincidunt eu. Nam tempus et est a hendrerit. Nunc blandit orci nec nisi tempus, id aliquam sapien porta. Morbi quis condimentum mauris. Cras a consectetur erat, quis laoreet neque. Cras mattis quis nisl at varius. Vestibulum ligula sem, imperdiet congue erat nec, congue euismod orci. Mauris vulputate neque eros, nec semper velit feugiat eu. Suspendisse interdum lacus a suscipit rhoncus.
\wrapfill
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

should produce something like this:

[image]